# How can we mock cassandra session using golang?

Tags: go, cassandra, gocql

Q : Is there any way to mock casssandra session using go without actually connecting to any keyspace/schema/DB. Can we mock cassandra for unit testing?

Answer (score 4):

In general the best thing to do is to use interfaces instead of the real cassandra library implementation.

You've not included an example so I've created on below:

```
type Service struct {
    session *gocql.Session
}

func (s *Service) Tweets() {

    var id gocql.UUID
    var text string

    q := `SELECT id, text FROM tweet WHERE timeline = ? LIMIT 1`
    if err := s.session.Query(q, "me").Consistency(gocql.One).Scan(&id, &text); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("Tweet:", id, text)

}
```

In this example we use the `s.session` field from the `*Service` method receiver.

Instead of using the session directly, we can create interfaces that allow us to later create mocks.

```
// SessionInterface allows gomock mock of gocql.Session
type SessionInterface interface {
    Query(string, ...interface{}) QueryInterface
}

// QueryInterface allows gomock mock of gocql.Query
type QueryInterface interface {
    Bind(...interface{}) QueryInterface
    Exec() error
    Iter() IterInterface
    Scan(...interface{}) error
}
```

Now our updated code might look like:

```
type Service struct {
    session SessionInterface
}
```

This means that we can implement the `SessionInterface` with a mock implementation and control the return values for testing.

Full code example of interfaces [here](https://github.com/gocql/gocql/issues/415#issuecomment-277530829)

Comment: Can you help with an example where we pass an mocked instance of a cassandra session. The above example is good but isn't comprehensive enough. I wandering if i've something like sarecords := summarizeRecords(fileid, "CURRENT_CHARGES_BY_SUBACCOUNT_SERVICE_TYPE", dat, Csession) where Csession := *gocql.session can we pass a mocked instance of Csession which is nothing but a mocked or faked version of the cassandra session.

Comment: in your `summarizeRecords(...)` method, type the function accepts for `Csession` would be `SessionInterface` from above and not `*gocql.session`

Comment: can i have a sample example where in we make use of the cassandra mocked session to query the DB.

Comment: -1.  From what I can tell this wont work.  If a method returns a pointer to a struct, you can't just create an interface for that struct that is returned.  Even an empty interface doesn't work.  From what I can tell, golang doesn't work like that.  Structural typing in golang is a lie.

Comment: @LandonPoch: sure you can. That is the power of interfaces. You can use them to mock out packages/code that someone else created without having to change that code. That is not possible with most other languages.

Answer (score 2):

This question is a bit old, but I also found the [gockle](https://godoc.org/github.com/willfaught/gockle) library, which contains an `interface` for the mock-worth driver components.  This library is referenced by the `gocql` library in the [README](https://github.com/gocql/gocql#ecosystem).